# Class 'Geocoder\HttpAdapter\BuzzHttpAdapter' not found

Tags: php, laravel, buzz

I installed the [geocoder-php](http://geocoder-php.org/) composer package using `php composer.phar install`. I'm running on PHP framework Laravel.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies
  - Installing willdurand/geocoder (1.0.10)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing kriswallsmith/buzz (v0.7)
    Downloading: 100%

willdurand/geocoder suggests installing guzzle/guzzle (Enabling Guzzle allows you to use the GuzzleHttpAdapter.)
willdurand/geocoder suggests installing zendframework/zend-http (Enabling Zend_Http allows you to use the ZendHttpAdapter)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

**paths.php**

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// The path to the composer vendors directory.
// --------------------------------------------------------------
$paths['composer'] = 'vendor';
```

**public/index.php**

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Autoload composer vendors.
// --------------------------------------------------------------
require path('composer').DS.'autoload.php';
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "willdurand/geocoder": "@stable",
        "kriswallsmith/buzz": "@stable"
    }
}
```

**Problem:** I get the following error when I try to run the example on Geocoder-php's homepage:

**Error:**

```
Class 'Geocoder\HttpAdapter\BuzzHttpAdapter' not found
```

**Occurs at:**

```
$adapter  = new \Geocoder\HttpAdapter\BuzzHttpAdapter();
```

**Directory structure**

[image]

I have already installed Buzz, did I miss out something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to require the autoloader before it can work

Try adding the following :

```
require 'vendor/willdurand/Geocoder/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Tried it but still getting an error. Using `require vendor/willdurand/Geocoder/src/autoload.php` gave the error `Class 'Buzz\Browser' not found`

Comment: Do you have another autoloader in your script

Comment: That is the only autoloader in the `Geocoder` package. However I can get it to work if I do a `require path('composer').'autoload.php';` from within the function that uses the Geocoder class. Could this be an issue with the Laravel framework?

Comment: Am not very sure .. i would look around and get back to you

Comment: Cool .... Well done .. you where have 2 auloader as suspected , one in Geocoder another in  Laravel framework

Comment: btw why dont you use the curl adapter, seems the easiest for me because on board?